# Two Tables, Match records step by step segment wise (Group by) un-matched goes as null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, wants to join them on step by step possibilities for the best match.

[image]

[image]

Basic Concept is divide both Tables in Cust_ID groups, like

(TableA)(A1) ~ (TableB)(A1) , withing this group first match them with SaleName, and then unmatched records match with Amount (-/+ 1), still any un-assigned records remain, those goes against null.

Then move to next group
(TableA)(A2) ~ (TableB)(A2), do same as above

**Let's take each record of TableA one by one:**
*(Since there might be few possibilities in records, i tried to explain them in detail with different examples in 9 records)*

**1st Record TableA:** Look for this record (A1) in (TableB), Found 2 Records * Put them in Unassigned List

Look for (A1)(Neal) in Unassigned list of (TableB)(A1)group, It found exact One match so returns it to Output Table

*** (A1)(Neal)(200)(U1) ~ (A1)(Neal)(200)(T2)

Other record of TableB(A1) is still un assigned which is (A1)(Richard)(200)(T1).

**2nd Record TableA:**

Look for (A1)(David) in Unassigned list of (TableB)(A1)group, found No Record, 
so now

Look for (A1)(200) in unassigned list,

found one record (A1)(Richard)(200)(T1), so assign it to

*** (A1)(David)(200)(U2) ~ (A1)(Richard)(200)(T1)

now, No record pending in Unassigned list of (A1)

**3rd Record TableA:** Look for this record (A2) in (TableB), Found 3 Records * Put them in Unassigned List

Look for (A2)(Thomas) in Unassigned list of (TableB)(A2)group, found exact one match so returns it to Output Table

*** (A2)(Thomas)(600.5)(U3) ~ (A2)(Thomas)(600)(T3)

Other 2 records are still Un-assigned

Since no records are pending in TableA (A2) group, these two un-assgined (TableB)(A2) records shall be put to output table with null

*** (null)(null)(null) ~ (A2)(Jon)(310)(T4)

*** (null)(null)(null) ~ (A2)(Jon)(200)(T5)

**4th Record TableA:** Look for this record (A3) in (TableB), Found 3 Records * Put them in Unassigned List

Look for (A3)(Brian) in Unassigned list of (TableB)(A3)group, found two records, Assign first against

*** (A1)(Brian)(450)(U4) ~ (A1)(Brian)(321)(T6)

**5th Record TableA:**

Look for (A3)(Bryan) in Unassigned list of (TableB)(A3)group, found No Record, So Now

Look for (A3)(251), found No record, End Searching and consider Null match
output will like row

*** (A3)(Bryan)(251)(U5) ~ (null)(null)(null)

**6th Record TableA:**

Look for (A3)(Sara) in Unassigned list of (TableB)(A3)group, found One Record, assign it to

*** (A3)(Sara)(320.36)(U6) ~ (A3)(Sara)(450)(T8)

Now out of total 3 records of (TableB)(A3), 2 are already assigned, one is still unassigned, and there is no match, so assign null

*** (null)(null)(null) ~ (A3)(Brian)(321)(T7)

**7th Record TableA:** Look for this record (A4) in (TableB), Found 3 Records * Put them in Unassigned List

Look for (A4)(Teko) in Unassigned list of (TableB)(A4)group, found No record, So Now

Look for (A4)(285) in unassigned list, found No Record, End Searching and consider Null match
output will like row

***  (A4)(Teko)(285)(U7) ~ (null)(null)(null)
Still all 3 of (TableB)(A4) are un-assigned

**8th Record TableA:**

Look for (A4)(Stephen) in Unassigned list of (TableB)(A4)group, found No Record, So Now

Look for (A4)(156) in unassigned list, found One Record (156.4), when looking for amount always look for +/- 1, assign it to

*** (A4)(Stephen)(156)(U8) ~ (A4)(Robert)(156.4)(T9)

2 Remained in (A4)(Stephen)(156)(U8) un-assigned List

**9th Record TableA:**

Look for (A4)(Elisabeth) in Unassigned list of (TableB)(A4)group, found No Record, So Now

Look for (A4)(102) in unassigned list, found One Record (102.6), when looking for amount always look for +/- 1, assign it to

*** (A4)(Elisabeth)(102)(U9) ~ (A4)(Charles)(102.6)(T10)

1 Remained in (A4)(Stephen)(156)(U8) un-assigned List

But there is nothing left in (TableA)(A4) group, so this un-assigned assigns to null

*** (null)(null)(null) ~ (A4)(William)(175)(T11)

Last column in the output is "status", if (Output.Amount-Output.Vamount) is between -1 to +1, then matched else Not matched.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way I would do this is to create a table variable (or temp table) that will store the results you want.  You write a query for your best match and insert those matches into the table you created.  Then you write a query for your next best match and insert those matches into the table but *only if they aren't already there*.  You can use `where not exists` or you can left join the table and use `where table.uniqueid is null`.  Continue through all of your possible matches in order.
So basically "if best match, then insert into table.  Else if next best match and it's not already in the table then insert next best match into table.  Repeat.".